# Can't raycast mouse click at good position on my map

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, raycasting

I decided to develop a game of gomoku, which the principle is very simple : you have to place circle or cross in a map of tile and the goal is to align 5 items. For that i choose to use unity in 2d and i use prefab with tile image to create my map. The problem i encountered is that, in my script GameManager, when i raycast my mouse click position, the click position is not the same as my tile of my board which i generated so i can't place item on my map.

> BoardGenerator.cs

```
public float startX;
public float startY;

public Transform tiles;

public int BOARD_SIZE = 19;

void Start()
{
    CreateBoard();
}

void Update()
{

}

void CreateBoard()
{
    float tileX = tiles.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().bounds.size.x;
    float tileY = tiles.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().bounds.size.y;
    float yCor = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(0, startY, 0f)).y;
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < BOARD_SIZE; i++)
    {
        float xCor = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(startX, 0, 0f)).x;
        for (int j = 0; j < BOARD_SIZE; j++)
        {
            Vector3 tilesPos = new Vector3(xCor, yCor, 0f);
            Transform tile = Instantiate(tiles, tilesPos, Quaternion.identity);
            tile.gameObject.name = "Tile" + count;
            count++;
            xCor += tileX;
        }
        yCor -= tileY;
    }
}
```

> GameManager.cs

```
public int firstPlayer;

private PlayerTurn playerTurn;

public Sprite xSprite;

public Sprite oSprite;

public enum PlayerTurn
{
    PLAYER1,
    PLAYER2,
    BOT
}

void Start()
{
    if (firstPlayer == 1)
        playerTurn = PlayerTurn.PLAYER1;
    else
        playerTurn = PlayerTurn.PLAYER2;
}

void Update()
{
    Play();
}

void Play()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        float xCor = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition).x;
        float yCor = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition).y;
        Vector2 origin = new Vector2(xCor, yCor);
        RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(origin, Vector2.zero, 0);
        Debug.Log("mouse = " + origin);
        Debug.Log("first tile = " + (Vector2)GameObject.Find("Tile0").transform.position);
        if (hit.collider != null && hit.transform.gameObject.tag.Equals("Tile"))
        {
            Debug.Log("hit");
            if (this.playerTurn == PlayerTurn.PLAYER1)
            {
                hit.transform.gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = xSprite;
                hit.transform.tag = "crossTile";
                playerTurn = PlayerTurn.PLAYER2;
            }
            else if (this.playerTurn == PlayerTurn.PLAYER2)
            {
                hit.transform.gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = oSprite;
                hit.transform.tag = "roundTile";
                playerTurn = PlayerTurn.PLAYER1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How you create your grid in the first place looks kinda wonky..  You seem to be using screen to world point, normally you just create the grid..

Comment: Ok thanks. So can you tell me which solution i should implement ? I searched a solution to simply put a grid in 2d in unity but i didn't find a good way to do it.

Comment: This is about [tag:c#], not [tag:unityscript]. this is also not a valid use for the [tag:visual-studio] tag

Answer (score 0):

You can take advantage of a different overload for the Raycast in order to return the object hit, like so:

```
Ray ray = camera.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
RaycastHit hit;

if (Physics2D.Raycast(ray, out hit, rayDist)){

    GameObject obj = hit.transform.gameObject;

    // Do something with obj

}
```

In the above example, 'obj' will be the GameObject that was hit by the Raycast, so you can get its position by then referencing:

```
obj.transform.position
```

The reason for:

```
GameObject obj = hit.transform.gameObject;
```

is that 'hit.gameObject' will return a parent object with a Rigidbody, if there is one.  This can lead to a lot of confusion down the track when working with more complex object structures, so it is good practise to grab 'hit.transform.gameObject', which will always return the GameObject that the collider the Raycast hit is attached to.